# how to find the user input is integer and use same input to compare with existing integer value

Tags: python

how to find the user input is integer and use same input to compare with existing integer value in python.

```
class Error(Exception):
"""This is base class for other exceptions"""
    pass
class ValueTooSmallError(Error):
    """Exception due to Value is too small"""
    pass
class ValueTooLargeError(Error):
    """Exception due to Value is too large"""
    pass

number = 10

while True:
    try:
        i_num = int(input("enter number: "))
        if i_num < number:
            raise ValueTooSmallError
        elif i_num > number:
            raise ValueTooLargeError
        break
    except (ValueTooSmallError):
        print("\nValue is too Small, try again")
    except (ValueTooLargeError):
        print("\nValue is too Large, try again")
print("congratulations, guessed correctly, i.e.", i_num)
```

How i_num will be validated whether integer value if not should be parsed on exception handling.

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: Please add what is wrong with your code. Expected vs actual behaviour? Do you get some error?

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking how do we know if i_num is going to be integer or not, we don't. As python variables are dynamic in nature, whatever value is passed on input will be stored as i_num variable. You have to explicitly add verification methods. Since you're already in a try block and you're using typecast you can easily gather any errors in case input is not an integer(it throws ValueError for typecast mismatches, so you can directly catch that):

```
while True:
    try:
        i_num = int(input("enter number: "))
        if i_num < number:
            raise ValueTooSmallError
        elif i_num > number:
            raise ValueTooLargeError
        break
    except ValueError as ve:
        print("Parameter passed is incorrect "+str(ve))
    except (ValueTooSmallError):
        print("\nValue is too Small, try again")
    except (ValueTooLargeError):
        print("\nValue is too Large, try again")
print("congratulations, guessed correctly, i.e.", i_num)
```

Comment: Can you guide me, how I can achieve this?

Comment: Please use the code I have mentioned here, I have added the following section in the code which should catch these errors "except ValueError as ve:
        print("Parameter passed is incorrect "+str(ve))"